# Wont Create New Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

My app currently has everything working properly with regards to Firebase login and database creation, then connection to my app.

I am trying to add a 2nd activity that utilizes the navigation drawer once the user is logged in. However, it only adds the activity in the android manifest and then throws the error below. I am using the nav_graph also.

NOTE: I added the activity last night just fine but made a mistake and deleted all the created files. Now I cannot add a new one. Any insight would be awesome.

[image]

This is how I am attempting to add the drawer activity:

[image]

Here is what I get. I tried adding again with a different name for the activity:

[image]

Comment: Instead of creating the activity manually and then adding to the manifest, i would suggest you to create the Activity using Android studio. This automatically adds the Activity to the manifest with correct path.

Comment: This is what I am doing. Android Studio only adds this to the android manifest. That is why I am so confused. I right click on the Java->new->Activity->drawer activity. Gradle spend 1 second building and all I get is the added code to the manifest.

Comment: Can you cross check the path? if you have created the Activity in any sub folders

Comment: I did that. Nothing new is created except for the entry in the android manifest.

Comment: I added a snip of how I am adding. It wont let me add image in comments

Comment: Android studio will suggest to create one new activity class with that name (as it couldn't find with that name). Try creating the activity using that.

Comment: It does but it is a blank activity. It doesnt have the drawer nor does it have the auto generated fragments it navigates to.